# TrustStore configuration issue in Spring feign with SSL enabled

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I have two different spring boot application with SSL enabled in it and also there is an eureka discovery server and these two applications are linked to eureka server.I need to make some https call between these two SSL enabled applications. So I decided to go ahead with feign client .Eureka is able to resolve https url properly for feign client. But while making the call I'm getting **"unable to find valid certification path to requested target"**. I can understand this error is because public key of my client application is not present in truststore of the application from which I'm making feign call. I have already added the public key in my custom truststore, But it is of no use.Property file for the same is below

```
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:springboot.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password= Pass@123
server.ssl.keyStoreType= PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias= springboot
server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:springboot.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=Pass@123
eureka.instance.nonSecurePortEnabled=false
eureka.instance.securePortEnabled=true
```

After digging more into the issue I found that "**server.ssl.trust-store**" property will set truststore in the embeded tomcat server of spring boot application, But some have my https call is taking default JDK truststore. When I added system properties in my application then everything is working fine. But with spring boot properties file configuration it is not working .

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStorePath);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",trustStorePassword);
```

I feel setting system properties is an workaround and I'm looking for a better solution .

I even tried enabling ribbon client and added "**ribbon.IsSecure=true"** property also. But still getting the same issue.

Can someone please provide a suggestion for the same.

Thank you